# Avoiding jitter when snapping diagonal movement to a pixel grid

Tags: c++, box2d, sdl2

Whats the best way to be rendering the locations of objects in box2D in such a way that there no stuttering on movement beyond 8-directions. I'm looking to have object strictly snap to the pixels but still keep objects moving smoothly without jittering.

every game loop iteration calls an Update() method on all `GameObject`s which rounds the objects position in the Physics world to a corresponding pixel coordinate and scaled up.

```c
destRect.x = std::floor(getX() * scale);
destRect.y = std::floor(getY() * scale);
```

drawn to the screen afterward in `GameObject::Draw()`

```c
SDL_RenderCopy(targetRenderer, objectTexture, &srcRect, &destRect);
```

this works fine and positions the object perfectly on the screen--too perfectly.

Moving straight in any direction is smooth and doesn't stutter. I quickly wrote the following code to fix jittering on diagonals (45 degrees) by ensuring that each row/column has only one pixel drawn on it. This makes 8-way movement smooth.

```c
if (IsMoving())
    {
        // Which direction is the object traveling
        float angleAbs = std::abs(GetAngleDegrees());
        if (angleAbs <= 135 && angleAbs >= 45)
        {
            CurrentCol = CurrentColY = NULL;
    
            // set y to floored object->x in scaled pixels
            destRect.y = std::floor(getY() * scale);
    
            // has this row been rendered to yet?
            if (CurrentRow == std::floor(getY()))
            {
                destRect.x = CurrentRowX;
            }
            else
            {
                CurrentRow = std::floor(getY());
                destRect.x = CurrentRowX = std::floor(getX() * scale);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            CurrentRow = CurrentRowX = NULL;
    
            // set y to floored object->x in scaled pixels
            destRect.x = std::floor(getX() * scale);
    
            // has this column been rendered to yet?
            if (CurrentCol == std::floor(getX()))
            {
                destRect.y = CurrentColY;
            }
            else
            {
                CurrentCol = std::floor(getX());
                destRect.y = CurrentColY = std::floor(getY() * scale);
            }
        }
    }
    else 
    {    
        // update any changes made to the coordinates
        destRect.x = std::floor(getX() * scale);
        destRect.y = std::floor(getY() * scale);
    }
```

This code tries to smooths out other angles that objects might move in (jumping forward, for, example, forms a parabola like shape) but doesn't look smooth when speed up to normal frame rates. The motion doesn't render seamlessly.

I think I'm rendering the locations of the objects almost too precisely, making the objects movement (ironically) *pixelated* and mechanical, but I'm lost on how to make pixel perfect motion on varied angles seem--or at lease give the illusion of--smooth "realistic" motion.

I'm looking for advice on how to approach this problem and find a working solution rather than make it work with my engine directly--all the same, the code for my game engine can be found on GitHub [here](https://github.com/AardhynDev/SDL-Game-Engine) if it helps.